# Find out what is primary key and foreign key on a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the following statement to get back the details of a sql table and it works, however, I cannot seem to figure out how to find out what is the primary key field of the table does anybody know how to achieve this.

```
SELECT c.name Field, 
    t.name Type,
    c.max_length MaxLength,
    c.Precision, 
    c.Scale,
    c.is_nullable,
    c.collation_name,
    '"+ tableName + "' TableName FROM sys.columns c INNER JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id WHERE object_id = object_id('" + tableName + "') ORDER BY column_id";
```

Ideally what I would like is another field on the above table to determine if its a primary key or a foreign key is there a way to achieve this at all even if its a yes or no boolean field?.

I tell you for why I am building a reverse engineer table to xml platform for Sage 200 and to make the correct xml i need the above information

Comment: Why do you assume the primary key is "a field"? What is a primary key? It is a constraint. Where do you find constraint information in the meta-data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the the query further below. Please note:

- I **only** test it for the scenario described (Customer -> Address) by the illustration below;
- Microsoft SQL Server version is **Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-GDR) (KB4019088) - 13.0.1742.0 (X64)   Jul  5 2017 23:41:17   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 6.3  (Build 17763: )**;

[image]

```
SELECT
    C.name,
    C.column_id,
    C.object_id,
    C.max_length MaxLength,
    C.Precision, 
    C.Scale,
    C.is_nullable,
    C.collation_name,
    FK.name AS FK_name,
    KC.name AS PK_name
FROM
    sys.columns AS C
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    sys.foreign_key_columns AS FKC ON C.object_id = FKC.parent_object_id AND C.column_id = FKC.parent_column_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    sys.foreign_keys AS FK ON  FKC.constraint_object_id = FK.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    sys.key_constraints AS KC ON  C.object_id = KC.parent_object_id AND C.column_id = KC.unique_index_id
WHERE
    C.object_id = OBJECT_ID('<table name>')
ORDER BY
    C.column_id
```

**--- Output for Customer table above ---**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the table and then press ALT+F1 type.  Scroll down to get PK and FK information

Answer (score 0):

TABLENAME indicates your table name

```
 SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='TABLENAME'
```

Comment: I dont see a field there in the results says primary key just is nullable no  but nothing that states its the primary key.

Comment: Please do not create multiple answers edit your existing answer for a change.

Comment: Kindly scroll down to see it